# Laravel LINE login (php)

Tags: php, laravel-5, line

I refer to [Laravel5.2 LINE Login](https://qiita.com/mayutan/items/9ff945f56718f5cb42cf) and try to login my website by Line.

But have some error in my project:

> "Driver [line] not supported."

[full version CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekta26rrzrgnw24/gocliginAuth%28IG%29.7z?dl=0)

CODE：

1.SocialController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;

class SocialController extends Controller
{

    protected $socialite;

    public function __construct(Socialite $socialite)
    {
        $this->socialite = $socialite;
    }

    function redirect(){
        return $this->socialite->driver('line')->redirect();
    }

    function callback(){
        $user = $this->socialite->driver('line')->user();
        var_dump($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code regarding this problem? If so please post that as well.

Comment: @Sand yes,  "full version CODE" to download

Answer (score 1):

Laravel *Socialite* doesn't support line driver.
If you want that, I think you have three options:

1. You can do with any HTTP Client (something like *guzzle* or *curl*)
2. You can use PHP SDK (something like *line-bot-sdk-php*)
3. You may find some packages (something like *socialiteproviders/line*)

*** Edited
I'm recently created laravel line package. You can check

> https://github.com/naingminkhant/laravel-line